# Camel CXF RS server embedded in a WAR

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

All the examples for running a CXF-RS server in Camel (with Blueprint), look like the following:

```
    <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:8000/CxfRsRouterTest/route"
        serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService" >

     ...
    </cxf:rsServer>
```

and then

```
<route id="control">
      <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer"/>
      <log message="test..."/>
</route>
```

But this doesn't make sense when Camel is running inside a WAR, as the `address` can't be arbitrary, but something in the context of the host application. (Additionally, how does setting a full hostname in the URL here **ever** make sense? Shouldn't it be port and path only?)

What I tried is to add the following to web.xml:

```
<!-- CXF servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In this case, when I hit http://localhost:8080/myapp/route I get:

> org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController invoke WARNING:
>
> Can't find the the request for localhost:8080/myapp/route's Observer

Is this scenario supported? If so, how to configure it?

Comment: Why the /myapp/route instead of just /route?

Comment: Because the app's context is myapp.

Comment: Where is that defined?

Comment: Digging through the camel-cxf code, it appears the default address used by the CXF class JAXRSClientFactoryBean comes into play.  A quick search on the same does not provide the answer.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the camel user mailing list; see here: http://camel.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="/CxfRsRouterTest/route" 
 serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService" >
```

Giving access at

```
http://localhost:8080/CxfRsRouterTest/route
```

Comment: This works! Just needed to make sure CXFServlet is also listening to the same URL pattern. But... not I'm getting:

org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController invoke
WARNING: Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8080/myapp/route's Observer

Comment: I think there may actually be more than one webserver running in your application.  Is this started via tomcat?  Camel CXF starts its own embedded web server.

Comment: The whole thing is running on Jetty right now. In my web.xml, I configured a CXFServlet and mapped it on /*. Maybe this wasn't the way to go? My Camel route is as exemplified above. I want Camel to use the host app server if at all possible instead of starting its own.

Comment: I have a project using camel + cxf - it has no web.xml.  Hence why I suspected more than one webapp running in your setup.

Comment: Oh... You might be right. But if it's not in an existing context, what is the address relative to, then? This scenario (embedded inside an existing web app) is exactly what I'm asking about, so I have to unmark the answer as accepted. Sorry for that... I also amended the question to be more clear what I'm asking.